# How can I ask two attempts, and so that a notification is displayed about the defeat, or win

Tags: javascript

I try to make a little game in which you have only 2 chances.
The number is generated between 1 to 3,and if this number equals id image,then this number is winner.
The images are changed by click.
But how can I ask two attempts, and so that a notification is displayed about the defeat, or win.
And here is the asynchronous code

```js
    var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src ='img2/aef715f93eadcdf77c4dfa3baf5859ad.jpg'

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = "img2/depositphotos_11097776-stock-illustration-treasure-chest.jpg";

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = "img2/sunduk-iz-duba-kod-ds-12-pod-zakaz-6284723_big.jpg";


  var k=Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)+1;
function mark(ID) { 
    var Images =document.images;
    var i=0;
    if(ID==k){
    document.getElementById(ID).src=imgArray[1].src;
    alert("You win");
    }
    else if(ID!=k){
        document.getElementById(ID).src=imgArray[0].src;
        alert("You lose");

    }
}
function TryAgain(e){
for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
    images[i].src=imgArray[2].src;
     k=Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)+1;
}
 console.log(k);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <img width="300px" height="300px" onclick="mark(this.id)" src="img2/sunduk-iz-duba-kod-ds-12-pod-zakaz-6284723_big.jpg" id="1">
   <img width="300px" height="300px" onclick="mark(this.id)" src="img2/sunduk-iz-duba-kod-ds-12-pod-zakaz-6284723_big.jpg" id="2">
     <img width="300px" height="300px" onclick="mark(this.id)" src="img2/sunduk-iz-duba-kod-ds-12-pod-zakaz-6284723_big.jpg" id="3">
     <button id="btn" onclick="TryAgain()">Try Again</button>
     <p id="demo"></p>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably clarify your actual question: "But how can I ask two attempts, and so that a notification is displayed about the defeat, or win". And what you have done to attempt to solve this